# Directx Figuring out where i should put my camera

Tags: c++, directx

I'm Still confused about the camera thingy...
I have terrain in X file formate.  It renders perfectly.  The problem is how am i suppose to know how to set up my camera position, look at...  I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Well you position your camera where you want it.  Above the terrain would be sensible.  You then set your lookat to the point you want to look at.  Usually this would be at the actual terrain.